# XMLStreamException has not been bound to a prefix. Stax implementation WebSphere

Tags: java, serialization, websphere, stax, wss4j

I have an issue trying to deploy a Web Services with a WSS4J password callback on WAS 6.1.0.43.

Web Service based on XFire 1.2.2

I have no issue on Tomcat 7.0.25 :

It seems to be related to STAX Implementation; IBM use their own on WAS.

If you have any tips.

StackTrace :

```
Caused by: 
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: The namespace URI "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" has not been bound to a prefix.
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp.api.stax.msg.StAXMessageProvider.throwXMLStreamException(StAXMessageProvider.java:59)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp.api.stax.XMLStreamWriterBase.writeAttribute(XMLStreamWriterBase.java:464)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp.api.stax.XMLOutputFactoryImpl$XMLStreamWriterProxy.writeAttribute(XMLOutputFactoryImpl.java:157)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.util.STAXUtils.writeElement(STAXUtils.java:366)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.util.STAXUtils.writeNode(STAXUtils.java:391)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.util.STAXUtils.writeElement(STAXUtils.java:380)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.util.STAXUtils.writeNode(STAXUtils.java:391)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.util.STAXUtils.writeElement(STAXUtils.java:380)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.util.STAXUtils.writeNode(STAXUtils.java:391)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.util.STAXUtils.writeElement(STAXUtils.java:380)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.util.STAXUtils.writeDocument(STAXUtils.java:285)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.util.dom.DOMSerializer.writeMessage(DOMSerializer.java:40)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the stax related jars (probably wstx-asl/stax-api/stax-util jars) from the XFire distribution in your EAR/WAR and set the classloader to PARENT_LAST. See if that helps.